# Why "instance Monad (Gang String) where " compile error

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Where I wrote following codes, Haskell won't compile.

```
data Gang b a=Gang{getGang::(a,b)}
instance Monad (Gang String) where
    return x        =   Gang (x,"")
    (Gang(x,log)) >>=f =   let Gang(x1,log1)= f x in Gang(x1,log++log1)
```

The compiler outputs:

```
Illegal instance declaration for `Monad (Gang String)'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Monad (Gang String)'
```

And after I used "ghci -XFlexibleInstances" to launch ghci and load the file, it compiles successfully. Why?

Comment: Um... because it is not Haskell 98, and GHC with no -X flags implements Haskell 98?

Comment: @n.m. Haskell 2010 actually, these days. Not that the difference is all that big.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Haskell Report restricts](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-630004.1) what's allowed to appear in typeclass instances (by default)

> (Section 4.3.2) ... The type `(T u1 … uk)` must take the form of a type constructor `T` applied to simple type variables `u1, … uk`; furthermore, `T` must not be a type synonym, and the `ui` must all be distinct.

Translating loosely, instances are allowed to apply to type constructors (not synonyms, so things like `List`, `Maybe` and even nullary ones like `Int`) so long as all parameters passed to the constructors are unique type variables.

In your case, `Gang` is a type constructor but `String` is not a type variable. It's not even a type constructor! It's a type synonym for the concrete type `[Char]`.

It turns out that this is overly restrictive. It's meaningful to relax the need for all of the passed parameters to be variables. It's even meaningful to allow type synonyms. Since these relaxations are not standardized, however, it's required that you pass `LANGUAGE` pragmas or compiler flags to indicate your use of non-standard extensions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}
```

Generally these pragma comments are vastly preferable since uses of non-standard Haskellisms occur located in particular files. You may as well keep indication of the needed Haskell extensions alongside.

Comment: [`TypeSynonymInstances` is implied by `FlexibleInstances`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html#idp14615552). (Something tells me that list does not give all implications though. Is there a full list somewhere?)

Comment: To be honest, I always wait until GHC tells me I need them :)